# Редактирование php файла построчно

Tags: файлы, php

Прошу помощи...

Необходимо изменить построчно файл, содержимое которого примерно такое:

```
<?php if(!defined('CMS')) { die('Отказано в доступе!');}
$CFG = array();
$_CFG['SITENAME']='бла бла';
$_CFG['HOMETITLE']='бла бла';
$_CFG['HOMECOM']='';
$_CFG['SITEOFF']=0;
$_CFG['DEBUG']=0;
$_CFG['OFFTEXT']='Производится обновление сайта';
$_CFG['KEYWORDS']='бла бла';
$_CFG['METADESC']='бла бла';
$_CFG['SEOURL']='';
$_CFG['LANG']='ru';
$_CFG['SITEMAIL']='admin@sait.ru';
$_CFG['TEMPLATE']='tpl';

$_CFG['TOMEZONA']='Asia/Irkutsk';
$_CFG['TIMEDIFF']='';
$_CFG['ALLOW_IP']='';
?>
```

Пробовал следующий код, но он этот файл корёбит весь до ужаса

```
    $f_arr = file($dir. "/includes/config.php");
 $f_arr[2] ='$_CFG[\'SITENAME\']=\''.$sitename.'\';';
 print_r( $f_arr);
 $f = fopen($dir. "/includes/config.php" , "w" );
 for( $i = 0; $i < count( $f_arr ); $i++ )
  {  fwrite( $f , $f_arr[$i]."\n");  }
```

Добавляя "левые" пробелы, пробовал $f_arr[2].="\n"
а из

> fwrite( $f , $f_arr[$i]."\n");

убирать

> "\n"

но там как то по лучше, но всё равно нужно, чтобы файл был как изначально и изменилась только одна строчка и больше ни чего не переставлять и не насиловать. Если найдется хороший человек, буду ему очень благодарен, просто это как бы и пустяк, но голова болит над ним.

Comment: Построчно? [Sed](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

Comment: **Пробовал следующий код**

**буду ему очень благодарен,**

А по нику и  не скажешь, что это парень....

Comment: 30 правило интернетов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользуйте `Zend_Code_Generator`.

Хотя, применительно к данной ситуации, я бы советовал хранить конфиг в `ini`. Инструментов для работы с `ini` полно, тот же `Zend_Config`.

Answer (score 0):

В таком варианте работает:

```
<?php
$sitename='11111111';
$f_arr = file("./config.php");
$f_arr[2] = '$_CFG[\'SITENAME\']=\''.$sitename.'\';'."\n";//тут двойные кавычки после одинарных для нормального переноса
print_r($f_arr);
$f = fopen("./config.php", "w");
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($f_arr); $i++) {
    fwrite($f, $f_arr[$i]);//тут перенос не нужен(он в каждой строке уже есть)
}
?>
```

Хотя, на мой взгляд, всё равно уродство.

Comment: В таких муках рождалась некая PHOTO_CMS )))))
Даже страшно подумать как там могут работать другие компоненты, если такая пьянка с обновлением конфига.

Comment: Просто бывает такое, что забыл о работе с файлами.
CMS для себя пишу.
К стати, ругается на на >fwrite($f, $f_arr[$i]);